# When is bias set to False?

Tags: convolution, gan, generative-models

I have been working with **DC-GAN** to generate pairs of images based on [**WGAN paper**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875). For which I referred [fastai notebook on WGAN](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/courses/dl2/wgan.ipynb) where the bias in the network has been set to *False*. Jeremy Howard in his video regarding the notebook asked the viewers to figure out the reason which remains unsolved for me.

[image]

Please explain why the bias has been set to False and when should bias be set to *False*.